# Alternative way to change the value of a property in a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two data structures:

```
let menu = [
  {
      name: 'category1',
      links: [{
        id: 'id1',
        name: 'name1',
        url: ''
      }, {
        id: 'id2',
        name: 'name2',
        url: ''
      }, {
        id: 'id3',
        name: 'name3',
        url: ''
      }]
  }, 
  {
      name: 'category2',
      links: [{
        id: 'id4',
        name: 'name4',
        url: ''
      }]
  }, 
  {
      name: 'category3',
      links: [{
        id: 'id5',
        name: 'name5',
        url: ''
      }, {
        id: 'id6',
        name: 'name6',
        url: ''
      }]
  }, 
  {
      name: 'category4',
      links: [{
        id: 'id7',
        name: 'name7',
        url: ''
      }, {
        id: 'id8',
        name: 'name8',
        url: ''
      }]
  }, 
  {
      name: 'category5',
      links: [{
        id: 'id9',
        name: 'name9',
        url: ''
      }, {
        id: 'id10',
        name: 'name10',
        url: ''
      }, {
        id: 'id11',
        name: 'name11',
        url: ''
      }, {
        id: 'id12',
        name: 'name12',
        url: ''
  }]
}];

const urlList = {
    id1: 'url111',
    id2: 'url222',
    id3: 'url333',
    id4: 'url444',
    id5: 'url555',
    id6: 'url666',
    id7: 'url777',
    id8: 'url888',
    id9: 'url999',
    id10: 'url1010',
    id11: 'url1100',
    id12: 'url1200'
};
```

I want to be able to modify the 'url' property of every object in the data structure 'menu' with the value in 'urlList', according to the matching 'id'. The expected result would be:

```
[
  {
    name: 'category1',
    links: [
      { id: 'id1', name: 'name1', url: 'url111' },
      { id: 'id2', name: 'name2', url: 'url222' },
      { id: 'id3', name: 'name3', url: 'url333' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'category2',
    links: [ { id: 'id4', name: 'name4', url: 'url444' } ]
  },
  {
    name: 'category3',
    links: [
      { id: 'id5', name: 'name5', url: 'url555' },
      { id: 'id6', name: 'name6', url: 'url666' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'category4',
    links: [
      { id: 'id7', name: 'name7', url: 'url777' },
      { id: 'id8', name: 'name8', url: 'url888' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'category5',
    links: [
      { id: 'id9', name: 'name9', url: 'url999' },
      {
        id: 'id10',
        name: 'name10',
        url: 'url1010'
      },
      {
        id: 'id11',
        name: 'name11',
        url: 'url1100'
      },
      {
        id: 'id12',
        name: 'name12',
        url: 'url1200'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this:

```
menu.forEach((a)=> {
  a.links.forEach((b) => {
    b.url = urlList[b.id]
  })
});
```

And while it works, it's obviously not the best way to do it. I've seen similar issues been solved with recursions, but I don't understand those solutions. Is there a better way without resorting to recursions?

Here's a playground with the code: https://playcode.io/1711570

Comment: "*it's obviously not the best way to do it.*" - why do you think so? What do you think needs to be improved?

Comment: You don't need any recursion unless the menu can be nested arbitrarily deep. For two levels of arrays, two nested loops are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const updatedMenu = menu.map(category => ({
  ...category,
  links: category.links.map(link => ({
    ...link,
    url: urlList[link.id]?.toString() || '' // Optional chaining and default value
  }))
}));

console.log(updatedMenu);
```

**Working**:

`menu.map(category => ...)` means we are going through each category in the menu array one by one.

`{...category, links: ...}` creates a new object for each category. The `...category` (`...` is known as spread operator) copies all properties from the existing category, and we will update the links property after `links:`.

`category.links.map(link => )` means we are going through each link in the links array of the current category.

`{...link, url: ...}` creates a new object for each link. The `...link` copies all properties from the existing link, and we will update the `url` property `url:`.

`urlList[link.id]` looks up the `url` corresponding to the current link's id in the `urlList` object.

`?.toString()` is the optional chaining operator. It ensures that if `urlList[link.id]` is `undefined`, it would not cause error. If it is defined, we call `toString()` to make sure the `url` is a string.

`|| ''` provides a default value of an empty string (`''`) in case the result is falsy (undefined or an empty string).

This approach is a concise and modern way to update nested properties in an array of objects. It uses the concept of mapping over arrays to transform data in a clean and readable manner.

However, whether it's **better** depends on factors like readability, familiarity, and the requirements of your specific use case. Your approach is also clear and straightforward, so feel free to choose the one that fits your preferences and the context in which you are working.